# Swift error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '()'

Tags: ios, swift, itunesu

I'm doing the course of iTunes University called "Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift". On the third video I encountered with a problem that did not happen in the video, even though it was the same code, that is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

…

@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber{
            enter()
        }
        if let operation = sender.currentTitle {
            if let result = brain.performOperation(operation) { > ERROR HERE
                displayValue = result
            } else {
                displayValue = 0
            }
        }
    } 
…
}
```

After reading many explanations of this error I suppose the problem comes from here:

```
class CalculatorBrain
{

…
func performOperation(symbol: String) {
        if let operation = knownOps[symbol] {            opStack.append(operation)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you if you can help me!

Comment: Does `brain.performOperation(operation)` return anything or is it a void function?

Comment: What is the error? What do you want this code to do?

Comment: performOperation method needs return an Optional Type. Swift it is really bad with error description but this one it is really well described

Comment: func performOperation(symbol: String) -> Int?

Comment: Code Different: brain.perfomOperation only appends the operation to opStack

Comment: Blackwood: I want to make an array of the operations done in a calculator.

Comment: Just make it return true (a Bool) or 1 then, if successful. (Not sure why your using 'result' if it doesn't come from anywhere)

Comment: If it's not returning anything and can't fail, do you even need the result let?

Comment: Leo Dabus: It worked with func performOperation(symbol: String) -> Double? Thank youu!!

Comment: Joe Benton: It is working now, but thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: @IsabelDíaz you are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

performOperation doesn't return anything and needs to return an optional type so that it can be used in your if let statement (to check if it did indeed return a value) and that's what it could be moaning about.

Try:

```
func performOperation(symbol: String) -> Int? {
```

which means it could return an Int, and then your if let statement should be happy.